# Composing permutations in factorial notation

Tags: algorithms, permutations

Given two permutations $p_1$ and $p_2$ in [factorial notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system), is there a direct algorithm which computes their composition *directly*, i.e. without translating to a different notation or via computing the action on a sample vector?

For discreteness, if you could show how $(2\ 2\ 0\ 1\ 0)$ composed with $(3\ 3\ 0\ 0\ 0)$ gives $(4\ 1\ 1\ 1\ 0)$, that would help a lot.  Note that I explicitly show the trailing $0$ in the above permutations (even though this is usually omitted).  The reason for that is that I am working on some codes in Agda with a dependently-typed representation of permutations (in factorial notation), and Agda forces me to be pedantically precise.

Comment: Is this maybe more of a TCS question than a math question?  It seems that this should be known, but Google has failed me.