# Indexing ranked permutations into other ranked permutations

Tags: algorithms, permutations

Consider all permutations of 0, ..., n-1 under some ranking R. Given two ranks, i and j, what is the rank of the permutation that results from applying the i'th permutation to the j'th permutation?

I.e., given some positive integer n, some ranking R of 0, ..., n-1, ranks i and j, and associated permutations I= and J, I want the rank of this permutation: [J[I[0]], J[I[1]], J[I[2]], J[I[3]], ..., J[I[n-1]]] under R.

A couple examples for n=3, R = lexicographic order (starting with rank zero):

p(3) = [1, 2, 0], p(4) = [2, 0, 1], result = [0, 1, 2], rank = 0.

Given i = j = 4, we get [2, 0, 1] indexed into itself is [1, 2, 0], rank = 3.

What I've come up with so far: I convert the ranks to their respective permutations via Lehmer codes, calculate the indexed permutation, and convert back to rank via Lehmer codes.

How efficiently can I get the rank of the indexed permutation from the ranks of the other two permutations? Precomputation given R and n is fine, and we can control R (so lexicographic order unless there's a good reason for something else). Storing the n! x n! array is not an option except for very small n.

Here are the n! by n! grids for n=3 & n=4, R = lexicographic starting at rank 0. Row i is indexed into column j to get the output. Note that the n=3 grid is identical to the top-left corner of the n=4 grid.

```
00|01|02|03|04|05|
01|00|03|02|05|04|
02|04|00|05|01|03|
03|05|01|04|00|02|
04|02|05|00|03|01|
05|03|04|01|02|00|

00|01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|
01|00|03|02|05|04|07|06|09|08|11|10|13|12|15|14|17|16|19|18|21|20|23|22|
02|04|00|05|01|03|08|10|06|11|07|09|14|16|12|17|13|15|20|22|18|23|19|21|
03|05|01|04|00|02|09|11|07|10|06|08|15|17|13|16|12|14|21|23|19|22|18|20|
04|02|05|00|03|01|10|08|11|06|09|07|16|14|17|12|15|13|22|20|23|18|21|19|
05|03|04|01|02|00|11|09|10|07|08|06|17|15|16|13|14|12|23|21|22|19|20|18|
06|07|12|13|18|19|00|01|14|15|20|21|02|03|08|09|22|23|04|05|10|11|16|17|
07|06|13|12|19|18|01|00|15|14|21|20|03|02|09|08|23|22|05|04|11|10|17|16|
08|10|14|16|20|22|02|04|12|17|18|23|00|05|06|11|19|21|01|03|07|09|13|15|
09|11|15|17|21|23|03|05|13|16|19|22|01|04|07|10|18|20|00|02|06|08|12|14|
10|08|16|14|22|20|04|02|17|12|23|18|05|00|11|06|21|19|03|01|09|07|15|13|
11|09|17|15|23|21|05|03|16|13|22|19|04|01|10|07|20|18|02|00|08|06|14|12|
12|18|06|19|07|13|14|20|00|21|01|15|08|22|02|23|03|09|10|16|04|17|05|11|
13|19|07|18|06|12|15|21|01|20|00|14|09|23|03|22|02|08|11|17|05|16|04|10|
14|20|08|22|10|16|12|18|02|23|04|17|06|19|00|21|05|11|07|13|01|15|03|09|
15|21|09|23|11|17|13|19|03|22|05|16|07|18|01|20|04|10|06|12|00|14|02|08|
16|22|10|20|08|14|17|23|04|18|02|12|11|21|05|19|00|06|09|15|03|13|01|07|
17|23|11|21|09|15|16|22|05|19|03|13|10|20|04|18|01|07|08|14|02|12|00|06|
18|12|19|06|13|07|20|14|21|00|15|01|22|08|23|02|09|03|16|10|17|04|11|05|
19|13|18|07|12|06|21|15|20|01|14|00|23|09|22|03|08|02|17|11|16|05|10|04|
20|14|22|08|16|10|18|12|23|02|17|04|19|06|21|00|11|05|13|07|15|01|09|03|
21|15|23|09|17|11|19|13|22|03|16|05|18|07|20|01|10|04|12|06|14|00|08|02|
22|16|20|10|14|08|23|17|18|04|12|02|21|11|19|05|06|00|15|09|13|03|07|01|
23|17|21|11|15|09|22|16|19|05|13|03|20|10|18|04|07|01|14|08|12|02|06|00|
```

Here are the factoradics for n=4. I left off the last digit, which is always zero, for compactness.

```
000|001|010|011|020|021|100|101|110|111|120|121|200|201|210|211|220|221|300|301|310|311|320|321|
001|000|011|010|021|020|101|100|111|110|121|120|201|200|211|210|221|220|301|300|311|310|321|320|
010|020|000|021|001|011|110|120|100|121|101|111|210|220|200|221|201|211|310|320|300|321|301|311|
011|021|001|020|000|010|111|121|101|120|100|110|211|221|201|220|200|210|311|321|301|320|300|310|
020|010|021|000|011|001|120|110|121|100|111|101|220|210|221|200|211|201|320|310|321|300|311|301|
021|011|020|001|010|000|121|111|120|101|110|100|221|211|220|201|210|200|321|311|320|301|310|300|
100|101|200|201|300|301|000|001|210|211|310|311|010|011|110|111|320|321|020|021|120|121|220|221|
101|100|201|200|301|300|001|000|211|210|311|310|011|010|111|110|321|320|021|020|121|120|221|220|
110|120|210|220|310|320|010|020|200|221|300|321|000|021|100|121|301|311|001|011|101|111|201|211|
111|121|211|221|311|321|011|021|201|220|301|320|001|020|101|120|300|310|000|010|100|110|200|210|
120|110|220|210|320|310|020|010|221|200|321|300|021|000|121|100|311|301|011|001|111|101|211|201|
121|111|221|211|321|311|021|011|220|201|320|301|020|001|120|101|310|300|010|000|110|100|210|200|
200|300|100|301|101|201|210|310|000|311|001|211|110|320|010|321|011|111|120|220|020|221|021|121|
201|301|101|300|100|200|211|311|001|310|000|210|111|321|011|320|010|110|121|221|021|220|020|120|
210|310|110|320|120|220|200|300|010|321|020|221|100|301|000|311|021|121|101|201|001|211|011|111|
211|311|111|321|121|221|201|301|011|320|021|220|101|300|001|310|020|120|100|200|000|210|010|110|
220|320|120|310|110|210|221|321|020|300|010|200|121|311|021|301|000|100|111|211|011|201|001|101|
221|321|121|311|111|211|220|320|021|301|011|201|120|310|020|300|001|101|110|210|010|200|000|100|
300|200|301|100|201|101|310|210|311|000|211|001|320|110|321|010|111|011|220|120|221|020|121|021|
301|201|300|101|200|100|311|211|310|001|210|000|321|111|320|011|110|010|221|121|220|021|120|020|
310|210|320|110|220|120|300|200|321|010|221|020|301|100|311|000|121|021|201|101|211|001|111|011|
311|211|321|111|221|121|301|201|320|011|220|021|300|101|310|001|120|020|200|100|210|000|110|010|
320|220|310|120|210|110|321|221|300|020|200|010|311|121|301|021|100|000|211|111|201|011|101|001|
321|221|311|121|211|111|320|220|301|021|201|011|310|120|300|020|101|001|210|110|200|010|100|000|
```

Comment: Is [this MSE question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/737582/composing-permutations-in-factorial-notation) or [this MO question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/165071/explicit-algorithm-for-composing-permutations-in-factorial-notation) related to what you're asking?